# Updating Eclipse context menu contributions on right click

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In my Eclipse RCP application, I have created a context menu in a tree viewer with some contributions that are added depending on the results of various property testers. Those property testers evaluate attributes of the model object which is selected with right click when opening the context menu.

When debugging, I noticed that the property testers are only executed when the selection in the tree viewer changes, but not on right clicking when opening the context menu. How do I get the property testers called when right clicking?

I need the property testers executed when right clicking because some actions change the underlying model objects and therefore should result in a different context menu. And the user might execute such an action and and open the context menu right after without changing the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `IEvaluationService.requestEvaluation(String propertyName)`... It does exactly what you need. You get the evaluation service from the site like all the other services:

```
IEvaluationService es = (IEvaluationService)getSite().getService(IEvaluationService.class);
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to call the evaluation service programmatically. The context menu is added via extension point, so 'm not sure where to call ist when the context menu is opened.

Comment: You should call it whenever the data model that controls the property changes... Don't worry too much if it is called relatively often :-)